# Create a pull request from a repository that is not a fork on github

Tags: github, git-fork, upstream

forking iss not allowed (for this repository on github). So what I did was I cloned the repository to my local folder, Then made my changes and did a commit. then pushed it into my own repository on github.

Problem, my repository is not denoted as a fork in github. So there is no way to create a pull request to the original repository.

How do I set my upstream in github?

I tried to set upstream using git remote add, and create a pull request using git request-pull. But while the commands were successful, nothing showed up in github... my repository still does not show as a fork

when I try to create a pull request from the website, pushing "new pull request" button, I only see the same branch, I do not see my own fork even when choosing "across forks"

Answer (score 5):

You cannot create a pull request from a repository that is not a fork.  On GitHub, all the forks, plus the main repository, form a repository network, which shares objects.  This is a requirement in order to create a pull request.

If you have push access to the original repository, then you can push your branch there and create a pull request from there.  If you don't and the repository owner has prohibited forking, then you'll need to talk with them about how to get your change proposed.

Comment: thank you. Yes I can go with the push to new branch option.